# getting the loading icon to appear while using the jquery modal popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have been trying to get the loading gif to replace the cursor while I am updating the database or loading. It does work when my tabs are loading but it doesn't when I am saving from the jQuery modal popup. 
when I debug and look at the rendered html it tells me it is displaying right before it makes the call style="display:block;" when I let it complete the save it switches back to style="display:none;" The below code is just a taste, sorry I can't transfer the actual code from the development network to here. Since I am using these popups for every edit in a huge application, I really would like to get the loading gif showing.

```
//using jquery to start and stop with ajax
var $loading = $('#waiting').hide();
 $(document)
   .ajaxStart(function () {
      $loading.show();
   })
   .ajaxStop(function () {
      $loading.hide();
   });
//my div
<div id="waiting" class="loading-img" style="display:none;"

$("#somePopup").dialog({
    autoOpen:false,
    height: 'auto',
    width: 900,
    buttons: { Save: ....
    // you get the idea

 $ajax({
      type:"post",
      url: "some procedure",
      dataType: "json",
      data: DTOvar,
      contentType: "application/json",
      async: false,
      success: function(data){
        //refresh main screen  and close popup
      error : function(errorstuff){
       //handle error
      }
     });
```

Comment: can you clarify if your trying to replace a cursor with loading gif or simply hide and show a div with a loading image?

Comment: I'm trying to replace the cursor with a loading gif.

Answer (score 0):

It won't work since you specified "async: false", signalling the browser to use the same ui thread. ajaxStart/ajaxStop methods will never have a chance to run. You should most likely remote the sync option to achieve what you need.